# Passing props from container component to nested route component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

How can i **share state between AppContainer and Home component?**

For example, i want put results object in the state of AppContainer for pass it to all other components.

In this app i'm not using Redux.

I've tried to use React.cloneElement in AppContainer but generate an error:

> Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components)
>   or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You
>   likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in.

**index.js**

```
<Router history={browserHistory}>
    <AppContainer>
        <Route path="/" component={Home} />
        <Route path="search" component={Search} />
    </AppContainer>
</Router>
```

**AppContainer.js**

```
render() {

    return (
            <div className="containerApp">

                {this.props.children}

            </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: Generally this is not a good idea from a best practice stand point (especially since you don't use Redux).Can you give an idea of what you are trying to accomplish? More likely than not, there is a better approach than passing state via the router.

Comment: Ok. Thanks. For example in the home component i've a search form and i retrieve the result, then i add this results to component state. But i want this results in the search component. Tell me if i have explain better...

Comment: i dont think you can pass state from parent component to state of a child component, either you use context (which is troublesome) or you pass the state as props to the child. thats pretty easy to do. why complicate things :P

Comment: Ok, i understand. How can i pass the state as props to the child? I've tried with React.cloneElement but give me an error. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

`React.cloneElement` is the right way to go.  For example:

```
render() {
    const childProps = {
        prop1: this.state.prop1
    }
    return (
            <div className="containerApp">

                {React.cloneElement(this.props.children, childProps)}

            </div>
    );
}
```

If this gives you the error you were previously receiving then the only reason I can think is that AppContainer is being rendered without any children prior to any route match.  You could mitigate this either by conditionally rendering in AppContainer:

```
render() {
    const childProps = {
        prop1: this.state.prop1
    }

    const { children } = this.props;
    return (
            <div className="containerApp">

                {children && React.cloneElement(children, childProps)}

            </div>
    );
}
```